# Spark randomSplit training and testing data row count always giving different results

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am testing some binary classification machine learning problems in pyspark and want to get values tipically analysed in classification models (Recall, F1 score and precision). I am doing this on jupyter notebook. In order to train and test my models, I am using the `randomSplit()` function.

In doing so I am getting inconcistent results for all of the latter parameters. I dug a bit deeper and realsied that even doing `count()` on the training and testing datasets, I was getting inconsisent results:

```
# Split data into training and testing sets
(training_data, test_data) = eq_df.randomSplit([0.75, 0.25])

# This was printing inconsistent results!
print("Size of training set:", training_data.count())
print("Size of testing set:", test_data.count())
```

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating further I found this article:

https://medium.com/udemy-engineering/pyspark-under-the-hood-randomsplit-and-sample-inconsistencies-examined-7c6ec62644bc

Which explains why everytime the `count()` function is called on the `training_data` and `test_data` dataframes, `randomSplit()` is run again. Therefore explaining why I was getting different results for the count and other calculations on these dataframes, as the `randomSplit()` was continously being recomputed in the background.

To solve this, thanks to Steven's comment below, I cached the test and training data sets and obtained consistency in my results.

```py
# Split data into training and testing sets
(training_data, test_data) = eq_df.randomSplit([0.75, 0.25])

# Cache result so that these datasets remain constant throughout the code
training_data.cache()
test_data.cache()
```

Comment: try to `persist` your dataframes, the counts should remain constant then.